# Export Django model data as MySQL file?

Tags: mysql, django, serialization, django-models

I'm writing a Django app that does scientific calculations for a client, and he wants to be able to export data as a MySQL dump file.  Is there an easy way to do this or will I need to write a custom serializer?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No need to use Django for this. MySQL includes a command to do it for you:

```
mysqldump -u USERNAME -pPASSWORD DATABASE_NAME > DATABASE_FILE.sql
```

Comment: This works, but I need to generate custom dumps on the fly.  Are there any gotchas with running this command from a Django view using the subprocess module to serve directly?

Comment: Not really, subject to proper locking to ensure two requests aren't trying to write to the same file at the same time. Also look at the [options for mysqldump](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/mysqldump.html) - you may want to use it with the `--single-transaction` option.

Answer (score 0):

If the table structure that you want to export is constant (it likely is), then it would be easy to write a template to generate it as a text output.  You can use either Django templates (they're not HTML-specific), or simply string interpolation.

something like this:

```
def dump(w, qs):
    for r in qs:
        w.write ("insert into tablename (fieldA, fieldB, fieldC) values ('%s', '%s', %d);\n" % (
            quote(r.fieldA), quote(r.fieldB), int(r.fieldC)))
```

assuming `fieldA` and `fieldB` are strings, `fieldC` is an integer, and `quote()` is the MySQL safe-escaping function.  The `w` parameter is a file-like object (can be a Django `HttpResponse` object), and qs is the queryset with the wanted data.